# Extend "popular posts" feed using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a social app, and in that social app I've done things like extend the feed if a user wants to scroll beyond the most recent 100 posts and I did that by `msg_id` previously or `timestamp`.

But now I'm trying to extend a `popular posts` query and the rows are ordered by the number of interactions they've received, but for instance multiple posts have 5 interactions.

Is there any way I can even extend such a feed in mysql?

Comment: How accurate does the extension need to be, and how often does the favourites change? While you could use paging LIMIT clauses, as the order changes items could appear in several batches and reappear in the list. If the list is fairly static I would probably go for this (given how thing repeat randomly in Facebook, I suspect this is what they do). Failing that reload the entire list, or store the list when generated for a user (probably just with the ids) and page through the stored list.

Comment: id say its pretty safe to say the order of posts only changes daily

Comment: I would just either store the number of of records already output and use LIMIT x,20 (assuming getting 20 at a time), or order by the number of interactions AND a unique field. So you know what the last records displayed was and you have a consistent order.

Comment: still so confused , but ill keep at it and try to let ur answer sink in.